# Tabular/array in captions

Tags: captions, footnotes, arrays

Could someone explain me why putting tabular/array environments in captions (figure or table) results in errors. Moreover, the error description does not exactly point to the issue, but just reads

```
Undefined control sequence 
\hyper@makecurrent ...
```

What I would like is: include a matrix in a figure caption.

I know:
- that my caption compiles normally as text
- that

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{aaa.EPS}
\caption{$\begin{array}{l} r\\ s\\ t\end{array}$}
\end{figure}
```

fails to work.

A similar issue happens in tabu environment: I cannot include `\footnote{$\begin{array}{l} r\\ s\\ t\end{array}$}`, though I can use `\footnote{Text}` and can use `\footnotemark` with `\footnotetext{$\begin{array}{l} r\\ s\\ t\end{array}$}` after `\end{tabu}`. Still, `\footnotemark` / `\footnotetext` messes up footnote numbering and positioning when several of them exist in the same table, so I wish having regular footnotes.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\foo}
\savebox{\foo}{$\begin{array}{l} r\\ s\\ t\end{array}$}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{Grenouille}
\caption{\usebox{\foo}}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly in both environments (figure, footnote inside tabu). \newsavebox{\foo} can occur both before and after \begin{document} (even just before where it is used).

Comment: Before or after works fine for me. You should make a mystake somewhere. Post as an edit your problematic code.